# Python logging with dict from file for a package

Tags: python, logging, packaging

I have a configuration file which I recover like this:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/repository/logging.json'
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    logging_config = json.load(file)

dictConfig(logging_config)
```

It works but my concern is about packaging the project. What is the best practice to adopt? Is it correct to use a relative path like this or should I create a module and import it instead of loading a `json` file?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You ought to vote… Any issue remaining?

Comment: Both your answers don't address directly the problem. However your comment saying that the best practice is to use a file could be ok if you post it as an answer. My question was: between a file and a module to import, what is the best practice. Your answers are way two obfuscated...

Answer (score 1):

## My App - Two-level configuration example

Example of project with two levels of configuration files:

- LEVEL 1: read the configuration from the sources/application's folder (virtualenv)
- LEVEL 2: read the configuration from the user HOME

### Python project structure

According to the reference [Packaging and Distributing Projects](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/)
a (modern) Python project should have the following structure.
In the package directory, I add a `__main__.py` for the main entry pointand a `my_app.ini` for configuration.

Here is the structure::

```
my_app
+-- MANIFEST.in
+-- README.rst
+-- setup.py
+-- setup.cfg
    src/
    \-- my_app/
        +-- __init__.py
        +-- __main__.py
        \-- my_app.ini
```

### Project's configuration

You must add a `package_data` entry in you `setup.py` to include "my_app.ini" in your Source Distribution.

For exemple, here is a small `setup.py`::

```
from distutils.core import setup

from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    name='my_app',
    version='0.1.0',
    url="http://url/to/your/project",
    author="My NAME",
    author_email="my@email.com",
    packages=find_packages("src"),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    package_data={
        'my_app': ['my_app.ini'],
    },
)
```

For backward compatibility with Python 2.6, you also need a `MANIFEST.in` file.

For instance, we can include all `*.ini` files::

```
include src/my_app/*.ini
```

To check your configuration, run the following command::

```
python setup.py sdist
```

### Default configuration for logging

The `my_app.ini` store the default configuration for logging.

```
[formatters]
keys=default

[formatter_default]
format=%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s
class=logging.Formatter

[handlers]
keys=console

[handler_console]
class=logging.StreamHandler
formatter=default
args=tuple()

[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
formatter=default
handlers=console
```

It has only one logger (the **root** logger), with default handlers and formatters.

### Main application

The `__main__.py` is the entry point of the application.

Here is the source code of `__main__.py`::

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging.config
import os.path

import sys

WIN = sys.platform.startswith('win')


def _posixify(name):
    return '-'.join(name.split()).lower()


def get_app_dir(app_name, roaming=True, force_posix=False):
    if WIN:
        key = roaming and 'APPDATA' or 'LOCALAPPDATA'
        folder = os.environ.get(key)
        if folder is None:
            folder = os.path.expanduser('~')
        return os.path.join(folder, app_name)
    if force_posix:
        return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/.' + _posixify(app_name)))
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser(
            '~/Library/Application Support'), app_name)
    return os.path.join(
        os.environ.get('XDG_CONFIG_HOME', os.path.expanduser('~/.config')),
        _posixify(app_name))


def run_my_app():
    # LEVEL 1: read the configuration from the sources/application's folder (virtualenv)
    ini1_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "my_app.ini")
    logging.config.fileConfig(ini1_path)
    logging.info("Starting...")

    # LEVEL 2: read the configuration from the user HOME
    ini2_path = get_app_dir("MyApp")
    logging.debug('Reading configuration from "{ini2_path}...'.format(ini2_path=ini2_path))
    try:
        logging.config.fileConfig(ini2_path)
    except KeyError:
        logging.warning('Bad logging configuration in "{ini2_path}...'.format(ini2_path=ini2_path))

    logging.info("Running...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_my_app()
```

You can add this entry point in your `setup.py`, like this::

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'my_cmd = my_app.__main__:run_my_app',
    ],
},
```

To test the entry point, you can install it with `pip`::

```
pip install -e .
```

Then you can test your application::

```
my_cmd

2016-07-16 15:47:35,613:INFO:Starting...
2016-07-16 15:47:35,613:DEBUG:Reading configuration from "/Users/my_name/Library/Application Support/MyApp...
2016-07-16 15:47:35,613:WARNING:Bad logging configuration in "/Users/my_name/Library/Application Support/MyApp...
2016-07-16 15:47:35,613:INFO:Running...
```

*Note: the `my_cmd` was launched in a Mac OSX*.

Her it is.

**EDIT: Project on GitHub**

See [Ini Cfg Demo](https://github.com/tantale/python-ini-cfg-demo)

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the kind of application you have, you can have several configurations levels.

The common one is two levels :

1. Application-wide configuration located:

   - near your application's installation folder (mostly for Windows applications),
   - in a specific folder (in `/etc` for Posix applications).
2. User-wide configuration, located is the user HOME directory.

For a description of directory structure, see this article on Wikipedia: [Filesystem Hierarchy Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

### Common application folder and configuration files

Mac OS X:
  `/Application/<Your App>` (app folder),
  `/Library/<Your App>` (lib folder),
  `/Library/Preferences/<Your App>.plist` (config file).

Mac OS X (POSIX):
  `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` (app folder),
  `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` (lib folder),
  `/etc` or `/etc/<Your App>` (config folder).

Unix:
  `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` (app folder),
  `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` (lib folder),
  `/etc` or `/etc/<Your App>` (config folder).

Win XP:
  `C:\Program Files\<Your Company>\<Your App>`

Win 7 (32 bits app):
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\<Your Company>\<Your App>`

Win 7 (64 bits app):
  `C:\Program Files\<Your Company>\<Your App>`

### Common user configuration folders

Mac OS X:
  `~/Library/Application Support/<Your App>`

Mac OS X (POSIX):
  `~/.foo-bar`

Unix:
  `~/.config/foo-bar`

Unix (POSIX):
  `~/.foo-bar`

Win XP (roaming):
  `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Local Settings\Application Data\<Your App>`

Win XP (not roaming):
  `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\<Your App>`

Win 7 (roaming):
  `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\<Your App>`

Win 7 (not roaming):
  `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\<Your App>`

### Common application folder and configuration files

There is a plethora list of configuration formats, but the most common are:

- Mac OS X:
  `plist` format, see: [Generate and parse Mac OS X .plist files](https://docs.python.org/2/library/plistlib.html)
- Unix:
  `cfg` format is similar to `ini` format,
  `rc` format,
  `json` format, see: [JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html),
- Win:
  `ini` format format, see: [Configuration file parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

Take a look at [File Formats](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileformats.html).

For the `ini` format, I recommend the excellent work of Armin Ronacher, see the [python-inifile](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-inifile) library.

You can also use a Python file as a configuration format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see how it is relevant to the question... The recommended thing to do in Python is to use yaml or json file for the logger. The question is more: if I create a package, how I deal with such a file. Is the procedure I use the Pythonic way?

Comment: You ask "What is the best practice to adopt?": the best practice is to use an external configuration file located in a "common" folder (depending of your OS). But you can have a default configuration located in your sources. Using a relative path is OK (make sure you add your *.json file in MANIFEST.in). You can use ``logging.config.fileConfig`` to read the logging configuration from a ``INI`` file directly.

Comment: Ok but when another user will install it with `pip` how this will exactly work?

Comment: In your ``setup.py`` you need to specify ``data_files``, see: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files